# how to solve this error "Error: recognize -- (FeatureNotLicensed) at: "OCRXpress Std" "?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, npm, ocr, text-processing

I am developing a demo app of OCR using nodejs. So when I tried to run my application using 'node app.js', it throws  an error like this

```
Server is running
Error: recognize -- (FeatureNotLicensed) at: "OCRXpress Std"
```

I followed the steps which are listed on "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ocr" 
but still facing the same error.
Here is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const ocr = require('ocr');

var params = {
   input: './node_modules/ocr/samples/images/color.bmp',
   output: './out.txt',
   format: 'text'
};

ocr.recognize(params, function(err, document){
    if(err)  console.error(err);
    console.log(document); 
});

app.listen(8081, (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server is running..")
})
```

What are the possible ways to overcome this error?
 please help me
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these keys provided by accusoft.

```
const express = require('express');
const ocrx = require('ocr');
ocrx.setSolutionName('AccusoftRuntimeTest');
ocrx.setSolutionKey(0x00000001,0x00000002,0x00000003,0x00000004);
ocrx.setOemLicenseKey('<LicenceKeyProvidedByAccusoft>');
```

After adding these three keys, My issue has been resolved.